# Is creating a new branch appropriate for a feature change limited to a single script file in git?

Tags: git, git-branch

My understanding about branch is that we can create as many branches as we require for testing new coding style or feature(s) or release(s) and merge to a different branch or master when needed.

In my case, I have just a small change in my code: Change argument that accepts JSON type string to a different type.

Now, can I create a different branch for just this change, so that I can have two versions of my script? Or is creating a branch for this is too much and has other ways of achieving this?

Note: I won't be changing any other file. There is only one file in which I will do the whole scripting.

Comment: Creating branches are really cheap, what is your aversion to creating one? It's basically just a pointer to a commit. Even if your change is small, there's no reason not to make a new branch even if you add just a single commit to it. Then you can merge it into your desired production branch(es) when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say Git is there to help you deal with code management and collaboration. It's up to you if you want to create a new branch. There's nothing wrong with creating one more branch or not.

My suggestion is to go ahead and create a branch. If something breaks, you can switch easily between branches and also work in parallel in two features.

Answer (score 4):

There is no real downside to creating a new branch.

**The size of your code change should not determine your decision to create a branch or not.**

No matter how small the code change, if you want to continue developing with and also without that change then you need a branch.

If you are working with other people on the same codebase a new branch will make it easier to initiate a code-review (I suggest using Pull Requests for this).

If you are the only developer on the application and if you have no desire to keep the latest commit on your main development branch working at all times then you could commit on that branch instead of a new branch. This doesn't really have any other advantage besides the few saved seconds of creating a new branch.

For your case I would suggest creating a new branch, test your changes, perform a code review if that is part of your workflow and merge when everything works according to plan.